# React's new Context API and Components with ref

Tags: reactjs, react-native

I am getting:

> "Stateless function components cannot be given refs.  Attempts to
>   access this ref will fail".

When simply wrapping my component with MyContext.Provider;

(react-native, as well as reactjs 16.3.x  )

The new Context API does not say, that it cannot be used when Consuming components also have a ref, but yet it requires the use of function to get the context value, and therefore introduces a 'stateless' component in a way, where there was none (none of my components are stateless).

Is there a solution for this?

```
export const MyContext = React.createContext();


<MyContext.Provider  value={{'key':'val'}} >

  <MyContext.Consumer>

     {

         (contextVal)=> (
               <MyComponent  ref="find_me_later_22" globCx=contextVal>
          )

     }

  </MyContext.Consumer>

 </MyContext.Provider>
```

Answer (score 3):

you need to re forward your ref 
https://reactjs.org/docs/forwarding-refs.html

```
import React, {createContext} from 'react';
export const {Provider, Consumer} = createContext();

export const WithContext = (WrappedComponent) => {
    return React.forwardRef((props, ref) => (
        <Consumer>
            {(value) => (
                <WrappedComponent ref={ref} {...value} {...props}/>
            )}
        </Consumer>
    ))
}
```